# I want to find $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_n}{n^{1/2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I had a question about this limit. Suppose $x_n$ is defined as

$1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,...$

I want to find $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_n}{n^{1/2}}$. I don't really understand how to approach this question, since $x_n$ isn't explicitly defined. I would like some sort of hint as to how to start. I think I need to use squeeze.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: OEIS: [A002024](https://oeis.org/A002024)

Comment: You're right that you should use the squeeze theorem. You could explicitly define the sequence yourself if you want: all the information is there. But all you really need is an upper and lower bound on the sequence. What form do you think an upper bound should take?

Comment: I am thinking that the lower bound be 1, and for the upper bound I am still lost; doesn't x_n grow faster than n^0.5? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll look at two values in the sequence where something seems to happen.  Note that $x_6 = 3$ and $x_{10} = 4$.  Why are these worth pointing out?  Well, the third triangular number is $6$ and the fourth is $10$.  More generally, if $t_k$ is the $k$th triangular number, then $t_k = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$.  For values of $x_n$ like the ones I pointed out, you might view the situation as being given $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ -- i.e., the $n$ -- and having to figure out $k$ -- i.e., $x_n$.

For values like those I singled out, this is not too bad.  If $n = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, we can solve for $k$ using the quadratic formula; since we want the positive value, we'd pick the appropriate solution: $k = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+8n}}{2}$.

What about the ones in between?  Note that, immediately after we hit a value of $n$ whose corresponding $k$ is an integer, we have $x_{n+1} = k + 1$.  If we were to solve for $k$ using the quadratic formula, we'd get an irrational number between $k$ and $k + 1$.  So to get $x_{n+1}$, we simply take the ceiling of our earlier solution.  In fact, this will work for all values of $x_n$ -- that is,

$$ x_n = \left \lceil \frac{\sqrt{1+8n} - 1}{2} \right \rceil $$

From there, you can find appropriate bounds to use with the sandwich theorem -- e.g.,

$$ \frac{\sqrt{1+8n} - 1}{2} \le x_n \le \frac{\sqrt{1+8n} - 1}{2} + 1 $$

Answer (score 1):

The n-th term comes after 1 term of 1, 2 terms of 2,…k terms of k plus some r terms of k+1

Therefore $$n=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}+r, 0\le r\le k+1$$

$$\frac{k(k+1)}{2}+0\le n\le \frac{k(k+1)}{2}+k+1$$

$$\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\le n\Rightarrow k\le\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8n}}{2}$$

$$n\le \frac{k(k+1)}{2}+k+1\Rightarrow k\ge \frac{-3+\sqrt{1+8n}}{2}$$

$$\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8n}}{2}\le k+1\le \frac{1+\sqrt{1+8n}}{2}$$

Depending on the value of r, $x_n$ could be either k or k+1. Therefore

$$\frac{-3+\sqrt{1+8n}}{2}\le x_n\le \frac{1+\sqrt{1+8n}}{2}$$

$$\frac{-3}{2\sqrt n}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4n}+2}\le \frac{x_n}{\sqrt n}\le\frac{1}{2\sqrt n}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4n}+2}$$
$$n\to \infty \Rightarrow \sqrt 2\le \frac{x_n}{\sqrt n}\le \sqrt 2$$

Comment: Your last line does not make sense, you cannot take the limit in some places and not in others.